# Imprimir valor de um dicionário

Tags: python, python-3.x, dicionário

Tenho essa questão pra resolver, preciso exibir a nota do primeiro nome na ordem de chama, mas só consigo imprimir a Key, a questão é essa:

Faça um programa em python que solicita que o usuário digite nomes e notas de 10 estudantes. A seguir, o programa deverá mostrar a nota do(a) estudante que aparece primeiro no caderno de chamada.

meu código até agora:

```
dicionario = {}
for x in range(0, 3):
    nome = input("\nInsira o nome do aluno: ")
    nota = float(input("Insira a nota do aluno: "))
    dicionario[nome] = nota

newdict = sorted(dicionario)

print(newdict[0])
```

como faço pra imprimir apenas o valor da primeira key do dicionario?

Answer (score 0):

Na linha 7, onde você cria a variável `newdict` que recebe o dicionário ordenado, você está alocando ele como uma lista, por exemplo:

```py
dicionario = {'Felipe': 4.0, 'Joao': 5.0, 'Ana': 7.8}
newdict = sorted(dicionario)
print(newdict)
```

Resultado:

```py
['Ana', 'Felipe', 'Joao']
```

O correto seria você adicionar o método `.items()` na frente do dicionário, veja:

```py
dicionario = {'Felipe': 4.0, 'Joao': 5.0, 'Ana': 7.8}
newdict = sorted(dicionario.items())
print(newdict)
```

Resultado:

```py
[('Ana', 7.8), ('Felipe', 4.0), ('Joao', 5.0)]
```

Então mostrando o primeiro item do seu dicionário com `newdict[0]` ele retornará a nota do(a) estudante que aparece primeiro no caderno de chamada.

Por fim, o seu código fica assim:

```py
dicionario = {}
for x in range(0, 3):
    nome = input("\nInsira o nome do aluno: ")
    nota = float(input("Insira a nota do aluno: "))
    dicionario[nome] = nota

newdict = sorted(dicionario.items())

print(newdict[0][1])
```

Veja mais sobre dicinários em python [aqui!](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#:%7E:text=a%0A%7B%27r%27%2C%20%27d%27%7D-,5.5.%20Dictionaries,-%C2%B6)

Comment: Muito obrigado, porem na saída ele imprime chave e valor, eu queria só o valor

Comment: Basta referenciar o valor com `[1]`: `print(newdict[0][1])`